# window.open() should open the link in same tab

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am very new to javascript, and written a program that will open a querystring as link.
I used window.open() , but the link is opening in new tab,
I want to open this link in the same tab.
The code is below.

```
var strquerystring;  
if(fromvalue==""||tovalue==""){  
  alert('kindly fill all the details');
}else{
  window.open(strquerystring);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use window location? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the name attribute:

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self");
```

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
location.href = strquerystring;
```

Instead of window.open.
It will then change the current URL.

Answer (score 2):

Use either of these:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking the browser to open a new window. Try asking the browser to open a new location.

So in your else clause:

```
window.location = (window.location + strquerystring);
```

This will tell the browser to navigate to the location given. Instead of opening a new window. Thus keeping you in the same "tab"

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the current URL:

```
location.replace(strquerystring);
```